# Getting the highest value from 3 arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

first of all thanks for your time.

I have a program where I roll 2 dices 3 times, their values get stored in 2 arrays.

```
    Dim Attacker(3) As Integer
    Dim Defender(3) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each pb As PictureBox In New PictureBox() {Steen1, Steen2, Steen3}

        i += 1

        Select Case RandomNumber.Next(1, 7)
            Case 1 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Een
                Attacker([i]) = 1
            Case 2 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Twee
                Attacker([i]) = 2
            Case 3 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Drie
                Attacker([i]) = 3
            Case 4 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vier
                Attacker([i]) = 4
            Case 5 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vijf
                Attacker([i]) = 5
            Case 6 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Zes
                Attacker([i]) = 6
        End Select

    Next

    i = 0

    For Each pb As PictureBox In New PictureBox() {Steen4, Steen5, Steen6}

        i += 1

        Select Case RandomNumber.Next(1, 7)
            Case 1 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Een
                Defender([i]) = 1
            Case 2 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Twee
                Defender([i]) = 2
            Case 3 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Drie
                Defender([i]) = 3
            Case 4 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vier
                Defender([i]) = 4
            Case 5 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Vijf
                Defender([i]) = 5
            Case 6 : pb.Image = Game.My.Resources.Zes
                Defender([i]) = 6
        End Select

    Next
```

Now I would like to let the highest the second highest and the lowest value's 'fight' each other:

Highest value Attacker against highest value Defender,
Second highest value Attacker against second highest value Defender,
Lowest...

Is there a standard method to do this or do I have to work with 'a hundred' if statements?

Thanks again!
P.S: I am a 17 year old recreational programmer so I probably don't have all the basics yet.

Comment: HAHAHA it's probably vb.NET thanks for telling me

Comment: Since it's clearly VB, I've changed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could order the lists, and then iterate through them together using [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Attacker = Attacker.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x).ToArray()
Defender = Defender.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x).ToArray()

For Each pair In Attacker.Zip(Defender, Function(attack, defend) _
                                      New With { attack, defend })
    ' have the numbers "fight"
Next
```

To break down the individual parts in the ordering line:

- [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
  orders the array based on the elements selected by the given
  function.
- `Function(x) x` is a function that simply returns what is
  passed into it. Since we want to order by the `Integer`s that are in
  the array (instead of, e.g. some property on the `Integer`), this is
  the function we want to use.
- Since `OrderByDescending` returns a new
  `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` while we want to modify our array, we then
  use [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert it
- And then we store
  it (the `Attacker =` part).

Comment: My brain can't handle this, I lost your code in the (function(x) x).ToArray() part

I simply don't understand this (what function?)
I'd be very thankful if you could explain this to me.
(but considering my basic knowledge and your time, I do not expect you to do so)

Comment: @fox125 I've added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: I'm going to thank you (although I just read I shouldn't because I reached 10 reputation) this explains a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array.

```
Array.Sort(Attacker)
Array.Sort(Defender)
```

Then you can compare index 0 of both array together and continue with index 1 and 2.